# Optimization of getPath between two nodes Etree Python

Tags: python, xml, recursion, elementtree

I coded a little function to get a path between two nodes in my XML tree in python like this :

```
def getPath(node, target):
    if node == target:
        if node.get('mnemo'):
            return node.tag + ":" + node.get('mnemo')
        elif node.get('repere'):
            return node.tag + ":" + node.get('repere')
        else:
            return node.tag

    for i in node.getchildren():
        tail = getPath(i, target)
        if tail:
            if node.get('mnemo'):
                return node.tag + ":" + node.get('mnemo') + "/" + tail
            elif node.get('repere'):
                return node.tag + ":" + node.get('repere') + "/" + tail
            else:
                return node.tag + "/" + tail  # prepend node to path back from target
    return None
```

My issue is that my execution time is multiply by almost ten. Of course it's normal this is a recursion function and my tree is from a XML of 200K lines. I have no clue how to reduce the execution time of my script.

Thanks

Comment: We cannot run your code (which is badly indented btw). Please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Search for `pyton xml` module